# Odd search logic using graph API

Tags: json, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

Have been using the search API and am observing some perculiar results in search results.

I know there is a Chelsea football game on today, so I do a quick search of anything Chelsea related in events:

(using the Graph API explorer @ https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?)

```
search?q=Chelsea&limit=5000&type=event&since=2013-04-28&until=2013-04-29
```

returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Chelsea Jam Tree Comedy Competition Night", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T19:30:00+0100", 
      "timezone": "Europe/London", 
      "location": "The Jam Tree (Chelsea)", 
      "id": "201322573339969"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea Basham at Fly By Night Club", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-27T19:00:00", 
      "end_time": "2013-04-27T22:00:00", 
      "location": "Fremantle, WA, AU", 
      "id": "119017388296997"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "The Chelsea & Alexis Show! with Special Friends", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-27T22:00:00-0400", 
      "timezone": "America/New_York", 
      "location": "Mark Fisher Fitness", 
      "id": "264038507064618"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Chelsea&limit=5000&since=1367173800&type=event&__paging_token=201322573339969", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Chelsea&limit=5000&type=event&until=1367089200&__paging_token=119017388296997"
  }
}
```

Ok, not exactly what I was after - perhaps the event's haven't been added / been made public.

BUT - if I search  (note the v before 'Chelsea')

```
search?q=v Chelsea&limit=5000&type=event&since=2013-04-28&until=2013-04-29
```

then voila - the football games are displayed.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Man United v Chelsea", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T16:00:00+0100", 
      "timezone": "Europe/London", 
      "location": "The Rising Sun, Hazel Grove", 
      "id": "518842844847325"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "FOOTBALL, Chelsea V Swansea City", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T15:00:00+0100", 
      "timezone": "Europe/London", 
      "location": "White Hart, Barnby Dun", 
      "id": "590753400942611"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea V Swansea City", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T15:00:00+0100", 
      "timezone": "Europe/London", 
      "location": "Lizard Lounge - South Woodford", 
      "id": "281525378649440"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea FC v Swansea", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T10:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2013-04-28T12:00:00-0400", 
      "timezone": "America/Toronto", 
      "location": "Scallywags", 
      "id": "516466885084282"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea v Swansea", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T15:00:00+0100", 
      "timezone": "Europe/London", 
      "location": "Stamford Bridge", 
      "id": "152203718287492"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea v Swansea", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T19:00:00+0500", 
      "timezone": "Asia/Baku", 
      "location": "Stamford bridge, Fulham road, Лондон", 
      "id": "649119368438501"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chelsea v Swansea", 
      "start_time": "2013-04-28T09:30:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2013-04-28T12:30:00-0400", 
      "timezone": "America/New_York", 
      "location": "Ireland's Four Courts", 
      "id": "404696952971017"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=v Chelsea&limit=5000&since=1367161200&type=event&__paging_token=518842844847325", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=v Chelsea&limit=5000&type=event&until=1367155800&__paging_token=404696952971017"
  }
}
```

So is the API faulty, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No, this is expected behavior. Imagine how many events there are that have Chelsea in them. Using a more specific query like `v chelsea` is the correct way to do this. The API isn't a mind reader, it can't figure how that you want football games from "Chelsea", but "V Chelsea" is likely to come up with football events because of the "versus" phrase

Comment: If I ask the API to return all events with 'Chelsea' in the title, as the API consumer that is what I expect to return (it doesn't exactly say otherwise in the documentation). the pagination in the results would help with the server load. Your explanation applied to google search would mean the search would stop after the 10th page. I appreciate your answer, but do also have any evidence to back up 'No, this is expected behavior.'?

Comment: So it starts returning results you want around the 10th page, I assume? I don't understand why you think that's faulty behavior. Why do you think the results are faulty? Those events that you wanted (I examined 2 of them), aren't particularly "popular" or heavily attended events, so why should Facebook return a Chelsea soccer game event over the `The Chelsea & Alexis Show! with Special Friends` which has the same level of "popularity". Also, no evidence other than a ton of Graph API experience.

Comment: And, even if they're "popular" events, FB gives far more precedent in search to the Query Term than the weight of the popularity. So basically what I'm asking is this: Why are you assuming Facebook automatically connects the search term "Chelsea" with a soccer team? If you searched `San Francisco`, why would Facebook assume you're talking about the Giants? See what I mean?

Comment: No I'm just highlighting the fact that other keyword search engines tends to give out more results than an absolute match on the query string. Even then I would expect that 'Chelsea V Swansea City' would return for the search of 'Chelsea'! eid:152203718287492 has 2005 attending but still doesn't make the result list. If I searched for San Francisco, I wouldn't expect Giants to be returned.. but 'Chelsea v Swansea' HAS the keyword 'Chelsea' within it and is the first word. Surely that should be returning for q=Chelsea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Search 'A' doesn't means you're able to get all result which contains of 'A' character. Search 'A' doesn't means you able to get "Apple". The database is too heavily to cover all possibility. So in order to get 'Chelsea V', you have to give 'V' and 'Chelsea' keywords. Otherwise it want to return 'Chelsea stadium', 'Chelsea player', and all possibilities? No, it's too huge results for server to process.